# AWS S3 bucket access token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an aws s3 bucket and want to share and sync data with my team and some other individuals (and later access this data in the cloud). This is easy with the aws cli (`aws s3 sync ...`), but since we are now in the situation where multiple other individuals from outside are involved, they don't have an aws-account.

What is the preferred strategy here? Is there a way to get something like a read/write access-token, which then could get passed to the aws-cli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to setup [IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/) users and give the access either though a bucket policy or on the user level.

With bucket policies you can easily define what paths users are able to edit and access.

When you [create an IAM user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html) you also have the option of creating one for Programmatic(CLI) access only which will give you a set of credentials for that user only. Just use `aws configure` and set the access and token key.

You also probably want to make sure you are using an IAM user yourself as it's generally recommended for security.

Comment: I Agree! @leander: Just to clarify... The other people do not need their own AWS account. Instead, you will generate an IAM User for each of them, then provide the Access Key and Secret Key associated with their user. They can then use this with the AWS CLI to access your account. Assign sufficient permissions to their IAM User to permit access to the bucket/path you want, but nothing more.